# Checkbox Label displayed in the next line if width of the label exceeds the limit of the Div tag

Tags: asp.net

I am working with CheckBoxList, the checkbox lables are displayed in the next line if the value exceeds the div tag width.

Is there a way by which i can allign the same on the same line?

```
  <table id="Table1">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="250px">
                            <asp:Label ID="deleteLabel" runat="server" Text="Select "></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td width="900px">
                            <div style="border-style: solid; border-color: inherit; border-width: thin; overflow: auto;
                                width: 356px; height: 100px" class="ccodes" runat="server" id="deletePanel1">
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxSelectAll" runat="server" Text="All" />
                                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkBoxListDeleteEntities" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical"
                                    Height="26px">
                                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>   
    </table>
```

Values are displayed as shown below. (for third value if it exceeds the width of the div (356px))

```
[] test1
[] test2
[]
test test test test test test test test test test test test test
```

Any suggestion how to make the checkbox label inline with the checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [`white-space: nowrap`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)?

```
.nowrap_list tr td label
{
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}

<asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkBoxListDeleteEntities"
    CssClass="nowrap_list"
    runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical"
    Height="26px">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```